# How to return a list of numbers from a text file from a varying location

Tags: python, text-files

I'm trying to import a list of numbers from a results text file using python. Problem is the location of the list varies depending on the size of the data required. My part of my results file I'm interested in looks like this......

```
Tip Rotation (degrees)
Node    , UR[x]     , UR[y]     , UR[z]
101     , 0.7978    , 0.7955    , -2.6071
102     , -0.7978   , -0.7955   , -2.6071
1303    , 0.7963    , 0.7693    , -2.6053
1304    , 0.7944    , 0.7150    , -2.5948
1305    , 0.7797    , 0.6616    , -2.5697
1306    , 0.7427    , 0.6074    , -2.5279
1307    , 0.6893    , 0.5509    , -2.4701
1308    , 0.6214    , 0.4914    , -2.3998
1309    , 0.5421    , 0.4272    , -2.3227
1310    , 0.4538    , 0.3585    , -2.2451
1311    , 0.3589    , 0.2848    , -2.1736
1312    , 0.2594    , 0.2070    , -2.1141
1313    , 0.1568    , 0.1256    , -2.0715
```

So essentially I want to make a list of the values in the UR[z] column, but the location of this block varies depending the on the amount of nodes etc. So I was thinking of say searching for UR[z] then returning the values in its column. Also I would like to do it with out specifying the number of nodes, but can do it if it simplifies it greatly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Just as a further note the rest of the results file is as follows!

```
SUMMARY OF RESULTS
Max tip rotation =,-2.6071,degrees
Min tip rotation =,-2.0493,degrees
Mean tip rotation =,-2.3655,degrees
Max tip displacement =,2.4013,mm
Min tip displacement =,1.0670,mm
Mean tip displacement = ,1.6051,mm
Max Tsai-Wu FC =,0.3904
Max Tsai-Hill FC =,0.3909

PLATE MODEL DATA
Length =,1000.00,mm
Width =,500.00,mm
Pretwist =, 65.00,degrees
Number of mesh elements =,  1250
Number of nodes =,  1326

VAT FIBRE PATH DEFINITION
Fibre path formula =
            2
-6.096e-17 x + 1.421e-15 x - 90
Number of partitions = ,    50
Partition No    , Ply Angle (degrees)
     1      ,-90.00
    25      ,-90.00
    50      ,-90.00

VAT Ply Orientations in each region
Region  , Angle (degrees)
1       ,-90.0
2       ,-90.0
3       ,-90.0
4       ,-90.0
5       ,-90.0
6       ,-90.0
7       ,-90.0
8       ,-90.0
9       ,-90.0
10      ,-90.0
11      ,-90.0
12      ,-90.0
13      ,-90.0
14      ,-90.0
15      ,-90.0
16      ,-90.0
17      ,-90.0
18      ,-90.0
19      ,-90.0
20      ,-90.0
21      ,-90.0
22      ,-90.0
23      ,-90.0
24      ,-90.0
25      ,-90.0
26      ,-90.0
27      ,-90.0
28      ,-90.0
29      ,-90.0
30      ,-90.0
31      ,-90.0
32      ,-90.0
33      ,-90.0
34      ,-90.0
35      ,-90.0
36      ,-90.0
37      ,-90.0
38      ,-90.0
39      ,-90.0
40      ,-90.0
41      ,-90.0
42      ,-90.0
43      ,-90.0
44      ,-90.0
45      ,-90.0
46      ,-90.0
47      ,-90.0
48      ,-90.0
49      ,-90.0
50      ,-90.0

ADDITIONAL DATA

Tip Rotation (degrees)
Node    , UR[x] , UR[y] , UR[z]
101 , 0.7978    , 0.7955    , -2.6071
102 , -0.7978   , -0.7955   , -2.6071
1303    , 0.7963    , 0.7693    , -2.6053
1304    , 0.7944    , 0.7150    , -2.5948
1305    , 0.7797    , 0.6616    , -2.5697
1306    , 0.7427    , 0.6074    , -2.5279
1307    , 0.6893    , 0.5509    , -2.4701
1308    , 0.6214    , 0.4914    , -2.3998
1309    , 0.5421    , 0.4272    , -2.3227
1310    , 0.4538    , 0.3585    , -2.2451
1311    , 0.3589    , 0.2848    , -2.1736
1312    , 0.2594    , 0.2070    , -2.1141
1313    , 0.1568    , 0.1256    , -2.0715
1314    , 0.0525    , 0.0421    , -2.0493
1315    , -0.0525   , -0.0421   , -2.0493
1316    , -0.1568   , -0.1256   , -2.0715
1317    , -0.2594   , -0.2070   , -2.1141
1318    , -0.3589   , -0.2848   , -2.1736
1319    , -0.4538   , -0.3585   , -2.2451
1320    , -0.5421   , -0.4272   , -2.3227
1321    , -0.6214   , -0.4914   , -2.3998
1322    , -0.6893   , -0.5509   , -2.4701
1323    , -0.7427   , -0.6074   , -2.5279
1324    , -0.7797   , -0.6616   , -2.5697
1325    , -0.7944   , -0.7150   , -2.5948
1326    , -0.7963   , -0.7693   , -2.6053

Tip Displacement (mm)
Node    , U[x]  , U[y]  , U[z]
101 , 9.2757    , -4.6016   , 2.4013
102 , -9.2757   , 4.6016    , 2.4013
1303    , 8.4491    , -4.2173   , 2.2646
1304    , 7.6214    , -3.8331   , 2.1175
1305    , 6.8005    , -3.4481   , 1.9597
1306    , 5.9917    , -3.0625   , 1.8024
1307    , 5.2006    , -2.6792   , 1.6515
1308    , 4.4320    , -2.3003   , 1.5123
1309    , 3.6888    , -1.9278   , 1.3887
1310    , 2.9721    , -1.5627   , 1.2830
1311    , 2.2807    , -1.2054   , 1.1973
1312    , 1.6116    , -0.8552   , 1.1323
1313    , 0.9596    , -0.5107   , 1.0888
1314    , 0.3186    , -0.1698   , 1.0670
1315    , -0.3186   , 0.1698    , 1.0670
1316    , -0.9596   , 0.5107    , 1.0888
1317    , -1.6116   , 0.8552    , 1.1323
1318    , -2.2807   , 1.2054    , 1.1973
1319    , -2.9721   , 1.5627    , 1.2830
1320    , -3.6888   , 1.9278    , 1.3887
1321    , -4.4320   , 2.3003    , 1.5123
1322    , -5.2006   , 2.6792    , 1.6515
1323    , -5.9917   , 3.0625    , 1.8024
1324    , -6.8005   , 3.4481    , 1.9597
1325    , -7.6214   , 3.8331    , 2.1175
1326    , -8.4491   , 4.2173    , 2.2646

END OF RESULTS
```

I only want to looks at the tip rotation data section!

Comment: I did not fully understand your problem. I guess you have a problem with the different position of the UR[z] values ? Did you consider to parse the file with the help of the csv module ? (Have a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: I am fairly new to python so excuse me if I don't make things clear or seem very trivial.
So essentially want to search for UR[z] then return the (26) values below in its column.

Comment: At the moment the results files are in .txt format, would .csv slow it down considerably?

Comment: Your file format is fine. Given the fact that you already use comma seperated values, the csv parser can be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using any modules:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    next(f)             #skip first line
    nodes = map(str.strip, next(f).split(','))
    #find the index of `'UR[z]'` in `nodes` list
    column = nodes.index('UR[z]')
    #iterate over each line one by one
    for line in f:
        line = map(str.strip, line.split(','))
        #return the desired column
        print line[column]
```

**output:**

```
-2.6071
-2.6071
-2.6053
-2.5948
-2.5697
-2.5279
-2.4701
-2.3998
-2.3227
-2.2451
-2.1736
-2.1141
-2.0715
```

**Update:**

```
with open('filename') as f:
    column = None
    for line in f:
        if 'UR[z]' in line:
            line = map(str.strip, line.split(','))
            column = line.index('UR[z]')
            break
    if column is not None:
        for line in f:
            if not line.strip():
                break
            print map(str.strip, line.split(','))[column]
```

**output:**

```
-2.6071
-2.6071
-2.6053
-2.5948
-2.5697
-2.5279
-2.4701
-2.3998
...
-2.5948
-2.6053
```

Comment: Thanks but it just returns that" 'UR[z]' is not in list'. Any idea why it can't find it?

Comment: @user2739143 Which one? First or second solution.

Comment: @user2739143 Tested both solutions again, and they are working fine for the sample data you've provided. Please post the data for which these solutions aren't working.

Comment: I've edited the the original results with the whole text file

Comment: Thanks mate, works fine! Although I'm trying to find the standard deviation of the list, so I appended them using tipNodeRotationValues.append(map(str.strip, line.split(','))[column]) and then work out the STD using np.std(tipNodeRotationValues) but it returns an error! Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: @user2739143 Try converting them to float before appending them to that list, use `float(map(str.strip, line.split(','))[column])`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (a big rough on the float parsing though):

```
import csv

with open('data.txt','r') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            print float(row[3])
        except: pass
```

Comment: Thanks, works of sorts, but the problem with that is there is another block of results after the one I'm interested in that uses row[3] so it reads them as well. Is there a way to stop after it doesn't receive a value or something?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('yourfile.txt',delimiter=' , ',skip_header=1, names=True)
```

Then access your column like this

```
data['URx']
```